# TextBlock Vs ContentControl in performance in XAML

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-8.1

I have a section header which contains two words to be displayed in XAML with a little bit of style with fontsize and fontfamily. I can implement this with **TextBlock** or **ContentControl** (by setting the **content** property to the header text).

The **TextBlock** is not derived from **Control**, so is the intent of TextBlock to perform better in XAML for text compared to a contentcontrol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TextBlock` is just that, a `TextBlock` as framework element when you invoke it is just an object. So when you write `<TextBlock Text="Blah Blah Blah"/>` that's literally all it is.

When you're using a `ContentControl` you're actually invoking a templated control that will have multiple elements in its tree that are added for every instance. So example you're using;

```
<Style TargetType="ContentControl">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                  <ContentPresenter
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                      Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
              </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
  </Style>
```

So a short version to your answer would be Yes, TextBlock will perform better and is suggested to be used over templated controls like `ContentControl` or `Label` etc. wherever possible.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: It' also worth mentioning that even if you use such a `ContentControl`, the text *itself* will end up being rendered by a `TextBlock`, which is automatically created by WPF. WPF has no means to put text inside the ContentControl other than using a `TextBlock`.

Comment: I don't usually drink beer, but it's okay ;) anyways, it's going to be really difficult since you're in Kansas and I'm in Buenos Aires =)

Comment: Some mysteries are getting revealed to me now :)

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question -- if your intent is to only always render text, yes, use only a TextBlock.  As others have pointed out using a ContentControl/ContentPresenter and setting to a string will wrap it anyway, and you have increased your element count +1 unnecessarily.